# Python 3.x about encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib.request as request

import re

url = "http://jjo.kr/users/38281748"

raw_data = request.urlopen(url).read() #Bytes

decoded = raw_data.decode("utf-8")

print(decoded)
```

---

I was trying to get HTML info about that url, but I got error messages.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character '\ufeff' in position 2313: illegal multibyte sequence

Am I misunderstanding the fuction `decode()`?

According to the Python 3.5.2 Standard Library decode "Return a string decoded from the given bytes.".

But I got cp949 instead of a utf-8 string.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: From which line does the exception come? I assume it's from the print, that tries to convert to cp949 to work with your terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got unicode string by decoding the bytes string.

But as you try to print it, python use `cp949` encoding (because it's your stdout encoding = `sys.stdout.encoding`)

There's `\ufeff` (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE) which cannot be represented in cp949 encoding.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name('\ufeff')
'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE'
```

You can ignore/replace such character by encoding with `ignore`, `replace` error-handler.

```
import sys

decoded = raw_data.decode("utf-8")
decoded = decoded.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'ignore').decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
print(decoded)
```

Comment: This is correct, except why first encode to stdout's encoding and then decode again?

Comment: OMG it actually work! you must be genius. thank you for solve my problem.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, You need to encode using stdout's encoding (which is used when you `print(..)`). Otherwise, it will raise `UnicodeEncodeError` as OP has got. Without decoding, especially in Python 3, it will print unwanted `b'...'` (Python 3.x's representation of bytes object)

Answer (score 1):

The decoded string contains a `\uFEFF` character, which is a byte order mark. I have no idea why it occurs in the middle of the page, but encoding it doesn't work.

Remove it with:

```
decoded = decoded.replace('\ufeff', '')
```

And it will probably work.

Comment: thanks a lot! but I think \ufeff not the only one that's causing a error.

Comment: @JakSa: unfortunately I can't test that because I don't have the cp949 encoding installed. falsetru's answer is more general.

Comment: `u'\ufeff' != b'\xfeff'`

Comment: `'\ufeff'` is not BOM, but `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, `b'\xfe\xff'`, not `b'\xfeff'`. Check `import codecs; codecs.BOM, codecs.BOM_LE, codecs.BOM_BE`

Comment: @falsetru: I think that changed in later versions of Unicode, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark : "If the BOM character appears in the middle of a data stream, Unicode says it should be interpreted as a "zero-width non-breaking space" (inhibits line-breaking between word-glyphs). In Unicode 3.2, this usage is deprecated in favour of the "Word Joiner" character, U+2060.[1] This allows U+FEFF to be only used as a BOM."

Comment: \uFEFF is the BOM Unicode character, how its bytes look depends on the encoding.

Comment: Ah, my fault. Nice to know. Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: @falsetru: I didn't know either, but note that the error message in the OP complains about _encoding_ \ufeff which got me wondering too :-)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, For me, `... encode character '\ufeff' ` saying it's a character (implicitly unicode character, because it's trying to *encode*).